# postgres server won't start

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I get this error when I try to start postgresql:

```
Use of uninitialized value $logsize in numeric gt (>) at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 235.
```

Line 235 in /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster

```
 last if ($currlogsize > $logsize && !check_running_postmaster $pidfile);
```

I'm using linuxmint 12 any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Is the variable $logsize set at any place in the script /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster?

Comment: yes there's a $logsize = 0; in line 195

Comment: and is currlogsize also set?

Comment: yes : $currlogsize = 0; and $currlogsize = (stat $info{'logfile'})[7] if $info{'logfile'} && -r $info{'logfile'};

Comment: You need to start debugging your script. Add a line before line 235 like this. `echo "currlogsize = $currlogsize, logsize = $logsize"` . That will show you the values of those two variables at that point in the file.